# Magento 2 Add to cart one product with different size at once but seems as one product

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1, addtocart, shopping-cart

I have created one module in which we can directly add products to cart using SKUs with different configuration options

[image]

but when i added it shows one product in cart with last option i selected and 2 qty.

[image]

I want to add same product with different options and quantities.

Proocess which generate an Array like this which i pass to store in cart :

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
        [WT09] => Array(
                [product] => 1817
                [sku] => WT09
                [qty] => 1
                [super_attribute] => Array
                    (
                        [141] => 167
                    )
            )
    )
[1] => Array(
        [WT09] => Array(
                [product] => 1817
                [sku] => WT09
                [qty] => 1
                [super_attribute] => Array
                    (
                        [141] => 171
                    )
            )
    ))
```

any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento core module retrive Product object using

```
            $product = $this->_initProduct();
```

as it checks in cart session and retrive previous Item Id if matched so all need to do is remove that function from out module and retrive product using :

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getId();
$product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
```

with this each time I'll get new Item Id and store it in session but if we already has same product with same configuration it will keep with same product and just append its quantity.

Comment: Thanks Ronak! I was having exact same issue and get it resolved using above trick.. +1 (Y)

Comment: @HimmatPaliwal if This answer help you to resolve your issue then you can up-vote the answer

Comment: I already did that :)

Comment: Hi Ronak, i need to add multiple products with multiple sizes on the Category page at once. Can you help me?

Comment: how can i help you @kiran

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is using repository approach for loading the product and facing same issue as I did.

After injecting `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;` into your class, use

```
$this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId, true);
```

the key here is the fourth parameter which "force reload" the object query and bypass the repository cache

in case anyone wondering how to get `$storeId` 
inject `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` into your class and use

```
$storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
```